# Inerting variables into a SQLite query

Tags: php, sqlite

I am new to SQLite and PHP so sorry about this newbie question.

If i use fixed numbers for the values here it does not throw an error, but this does..?

```
if (isset($_POST['l'])) { 
$query ='INSERT INTO clickmap (x, y, location) ' .
'VALUES (' . $_POST['x'] . ',' . $_POST['y'] . ',' . $_POST['l'] . ') ';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error? What are the values of those variables?

Comment: and what about if you use your post variables as $_POST["x"] and not $_POST['x']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concatenations are wrong, I can't understand nothing from that, you can try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['l'])) { 
    $query = "INSERT INTO clickmap (x, y, location) VALUES ('".$_POST['x']."', '".$_POST['y']."', '".$_POST['l']."')";
}
```

Comment: Yep you were correct, i had a bit of spaghetti there. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the POST variables directly into a query, it's not safe (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

So do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['l']))
{
    $x = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x']);
    $y = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['y']);
    $l = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['l']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `clickmap` (`x`, `y`, `location`) VALUES ('$x', '$y', '$l')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query into double quotes, or put double quotes in your $_POST-references. `$query = "INSERT INTO ...";`